# How to add image as button in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiimage

I want to add image as button, and when it is clicked it should open a new view controller...
Does anyone know how to do?

I created a button and added image, but its not nice, because when I click on the image it animates a square arround the image, which I do not want. This what I did.

```
- (void)setTutorialButtonImage
{
    [self.tutorialButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"app_logo.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Does any one know how to do... just an image and when I click on it start a new controller

Comment: It's the way you did... How was the button presented? Did you set it as UIButtonTypeCUstom?

Comment: you could just put an image with a blank button above it

Comment: just do UIButton with custom style, do set adjustsImageWhenHighlighted to NO and maybe use touch down control event instead of touch up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the highlighting effect by using

```
self.tutorialButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try setting the same image for selected and highlighted states too

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"app_logo.png"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"app_logo.png"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```

For better look and feel you can apply insets on image using

```
- (UIImage *)resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *sampleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[sampleButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[sampleButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[sampleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:sampleButton];
```